# Is it always okay to Inflate zlib-wrapped data with the windowBits of 15?

Tags: c, zlib, deflate, inflate

If the zlib-wrapped data to *Inflate* has, in its zlib header, `CINFO` (which determines the LZ77 window size) that is **other than** 7 (the maximum valid), is it okay to Inflate it with the `windowBits` of 15 (usually the value of `MAX_WBITS`)?

I ask this question as everyone seems to do so and not care about the `CINFO`.

Did I misunderstood something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's okay. The windowBits needs to be greater than or equal to the window size that the data was compressed with. It is always ok to decompress with the maximum window size (15).

Comment: Would a greater `windowBits` be better in decompression performance than the corresponding `windowBits` (that is, equal to the window size the data was compressed with)?

Comment: No. It would make no difference.